# Angular JS | Passing data to 2 differents controllers on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got some projects displayed in divs via ng-repeat.
Each div contains a link with the id of the project.

Basically I want to bind my project id on ng-click in order to update a factory. This will allow me to share the clicked project's id with another controller who will load the project details data only.

Here is my projects view:

```
<div ng-repeat="detail in projects.details">
    <a ng-href="#!/project/project-details" ng-click="setId(detail.project_id)"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

Here is my factory:

```
app.factory('getGoodIdProjectDetails', function (){
    var savedId = 1; //Default à 1
    return {
    getId : function () {
       return savedId;
    },
    setId:function(idGet){
       savedId = idGet;
       return savedId;
    }
}      
});
```

Here are my controllers:

```
function ProjectCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout, getGoodIdProjectDetails) {
     $scope.setId = function (idGet) {
         $scope.idProjectDetails = getGoodIdProjectDetails.setId(idGet);
     };
}

function ProjectDetailsCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout, getGoodIdProjectDetails) {
    $scope.idProjectDetails = getGoodIdProjectDetails.getId();
}
```

In my view the console is displaying an error like I can't bind ng-click this way, but when I inspect the view it's sorting me the good thing, like  `ng-click="setId(8)"`

I want the factory to update with the good id on click. Then I want to access this id in `projectDetailsCtrl` in order to load the project.

|| EDIT || : I changed the ng-click, that works fine, everything's good. Thx all

Comment: This is a perfect case for using a state based routing system like angular-ui router. In that case your id would simply be a stateParam or (depending on your backend), part of your url path.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="detail in projects.details">
    <a ng-href="#!/project/project-details" ng-click="setId(detail.project_id)"><span>Voir le projet ></span></a>
</div>
```

you don't need to use binding expression {{}} to pass values to functions